# Rails - how to pass created record from the new form to a redirected page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this is a pretty simple question but nothing I've read has answered my question directly:

I have a new products page with a standard form. After successfully submitting the form, I redirect to a custom controller action and view called "thanks".

On the "thanks" page, I want to be able to print the name of the product just created and possibly some other attributes.

How do I pass the object just created into my new action? Right now the controller looks like this:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    if @product.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created Product."
    redirect_to thanks_path
    else
    render :action => 'new'
    end
end

def thanks
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send object through redirect.

There are three ways to solve your problem:

1. Render the 'thanks' template directly(not action #thanks)

   ```
   render 'thanks' # thanks template
   ```

   You can send whatever instance variable to this template directly. `#thanks` is no longer needed in this case.

   Drawback: The url won't be changed.
2. Convey messages through session

   If you want to show certain messages, you can prepare it in `#create` and send it through `session` or `flash`(part of session actually). `flash` is better as you don't need to clear it manually.

   Note: You may want to use ActiveRecord as session storage if the message size is big, otherwise you'll meet CookiesOverflow by default setting.
3. Send very simple message through session say obj_id

   Similar to #2 but I thinks this is better than #2. In `#thanks`, you can construct complex message according to if obj_id is present, what is the id and then find related data through db.

Comment: #1 is probably your best bet. FWIW, you can send an object along with a redirect, sort-of, it's just a standard URT like any other... Constructing elaborate messages and passing them around in the session, as in #2, is not a great approach.

Comment: @BradWerth, thanks for your reminder. I just remember there is one more solution which is modification of #2 but better.

Comment: Yes, much better to pass around the reference, to be handled elsewhere.

Comment: Also, good point about the URL not being changed - you may want to do a manual hit on your analytics with option #1 (which is the way to go)...

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How do you do a manual hit on the analytics with a conditional render? Some kind of script in the partial being rendered?

Comment: @BradWerth, a manual mention for new question. would you elaborate that to Zephyr4434.

Answer (score 2):

You have two fairly decent options.

First, you could adjust the thanks_path route to take an id parameter, and call it like `redirect_to thanks_path(@product)`. Then you can call it up in your thank you method like any standard show method. It might be worth mentioning that if you are going to be displaying sensitive information on the thank you screen, you may want to use a random uuid, instead of an id, to look up the product.

A better way might be to not redirect at all, but rather adjust your view from simply drawing the form to something like this:

```
<% if @product && !@product.new_record %>
  THANK YOU MESSAGE GOES HERE
<% else %>
  EXISTING FORM GOES HERE
<% end %>
```

Comment: In this case I will avoid query string when possible. Suppose this is a book store, you purchased a book and got redirected to thanks page which containing download link. After one success purchase, you'll be able to download other book by construct url manually :) Ah, I see "random uuid" just now, that could avoid this problem.

Comment: Yeah, you could easily verify that the user accessing the page is the user associated with the order. In a secure application, this would likely be done, anyway. For everything else, the UUID is probably good enough. I personally use option #2 in all of my apps, FWIW.